# WSO2 Identity Server SCIM API to retrieve list of User

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I need to retrieve list of user details based on user ids.  I Know there is a way to do to get user details by using  SCIM call with filter, for example https://host:port/wso2/scim/Users?filter=userNameEqmyuser . But, what I need is user details for list of user for given user ids say 100. So each time, invoking above API for 100 times is time consuming activity and it takes around 10 sec.  I found there is one more SCIM call which gives you all the users present in the system by using https://host:port/wso2/scim/Users and pick the user ids which I need from the response. However, this API is also time consuming it takes around 30sec to return about 100 user details. So is there any way I can optimise the result ? I mean is there any way I can get user details for given 100 users in very less time.

Comment: Which IS version are you trying?

Comment: I am using 5.0.

Comment: IS 5.0 had performance issues with SCIM list user API. Can you try with latest IS 5.2.0?

Comment: @pulasthi7 - That cannot be done right now, since it requires more time to do so.